No output to command-line logcat from debug build Kotlin Jetpack Android app
I plug in my device via usb and do Run on MainActivity which installs to the device
While connected to Android Studio the Logcat pane works as expected
When app runs on device, or is restarted there, no command-line logcat output can be retrieved using either:
adb -s serial shell logcat -d --format=printable,uid,usec,year
or same command issued from on-device rooted shell
there is lots of output otherwise including the intent launches of my app
.
How can I get logcat to work?
on Pixel 3: Settings — System — Developer options — Logging level: Debug
in app/build.gradle.kts, buildTypes{ has no debug entry (ie. settings are default)
Is this perhaps some security feature of newer Androids?

August 24 2024
Android 12, Pixel 3
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2
debug build

.
How can I get logcat to work?

You should also attach the Output Snapshot of your attempt, and did you make sure all those log's you are externally written are in log.d() since you're filtering level to debug mode?

It started working
What I think the fix is is to first apply the developer option setting
then force-quit/reinstall the application
the log statements are not removed by something like ProGuard since logging works while connected to Android Studio
It seems to be a good idea for the entire app to use the same tag since it is difficult to filter logcat output otherwise like trying to chase a user ID which requires root and is different per device or a process ID that is different for each app launch
You can check if the build is debuggable using aapt from Android sdk:
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt dump badging ~/.apk | grep -c application-debuggable
1

